# Connect to Neo4j Causal Cluster using neo4jclient

Tags: c#, .net-core, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using neo4jClient with a causal cluster hosted on aws via the AMI.

I just recently moved across to this setup before i was using a single server now its multiple (3 in my case).

How do i correctly configure the connection string to connect to a cluster so that the neo4j client is aware of the whole cluster and can distribute reads writes etc correctly?

Running this command gives me all the servers in my cluster.

```
CALL dbms.cluster.routing.getServers()

[
    {
        "addresses": [
            "100.100.100.1:7687"
        ],
        "role": "WRITE"
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            "100.100.100.2:7687",
            "100.100.100.3:7687"
        ],
        "role": "READ"
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            "100.100.100.1:7687",
            "100.100.100.2:7687",
            "100.100.100.3:7687"
        ],
        "role": "ROUTE"
    }
]
```

Currently i have my neo4jclient setup connecting to the instance labeled 'Write', will it automatically discover the other servers?

```
services.AddSingleton(s => NeoServerConfiguration.GetConfiguration(new Uri(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Neo4jConnection")), appSettings.Neo4jUser, appSettings.Neo4jPassword));
```

The NeoServerConfiguration only seems to allow you to connect to a single instance not specify multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Neo4jClient` - you need to be using the `BoltGraphClient` and then the URI you connect to is:

`bolt+routing://100.100.100.1:7687`

Though it could be any of your IPs.

It won't work with the standard `http` endpoint - so you need to use `bolt`.

If you're using the `Neo4j-Driver` and you're trying version `4.x` - then instead of `bolt+routing` you would use `neo4j` (i.e. `neo4j://ip`)

Comment: Thanks, could not find this anywhere in the documentation. 
Luckily i moved across to using the bolt client a while ago too :)

Comment: The URI is always in the same format that Neo4j uses itself - so the docs for the connection URI are at: https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/client-applications/#driver-connection-uris  (atm :))

Comment: Ah ok, i was getting my info off of the Neo4jClient Wiki (https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting) which does not specifically mention that. Anyway once again thanks for the help.

Comment: Ha - no - it doesn't even mention `BoltGraphClient` - I think that page was even pre-causal cluster!